# MYSQL: Possible to mirror/sync two tables in separate dbs (same server) in realtime?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.1

I have two databases with the exact same structure (basicly two vbulletin forums), however the data contained within the databases is different, and will be different on a minute-minute basis.  I wanted to synchronize/mirror the data in one of the tables between the two databases (the tables have an identical structure and reside on the same physical server).  By synchronize it would take the latest changed data and apply it to the other database table, regardless of which one was changed

Is this possible?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have auto incrementing primary keys, you're hosed, so I hope you have GUIDs...

If sounds like a trigger would work for you, but each database would have to know if it was the *origin* of the row so as to run the insert on the other database.

Set a session variable that contains the current database name before you change the data.  The trigger can compare that value to the value of `DATABASE()`; if the same, write the record to the other database as well.

Comment: if you change the auto_increment and auto_increment_offset values on both servers, auto incrementing primary key conflicts are not an issue

Comment: Except that he stated that his databases _currently_ _contained_ _data_.

Comment: true that does create an issue for data already present... deleted my answer as missed the part about on the same physical server too, so they would have the same auto increment values... not really sure what the benefit of keeping copies of the same table in 2 dbs on the same server are when you can query/join between databases as long as the user has permission on the table in the other database

Comment: I figured he was iterating some other tables or his application code.  Maybe he'll explain.